# Browser does not pass the querystring to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a webpage where I am trying to read the querystring and do some calculations based on it. This page already has viewstate enabled. But on postback calls, this querystring is not passed on to IIS. My server receives the default url, even though browser display querystring in the address bar.

I don't know how to proceed with this. Or what code should I add here to help figure out the problem.

Edit:

Asp.net button definition

```
<INPUT class="DefaultButtons" id="btnSave" onclick="return fnSave();" type="submit" value="Save" name="btnSave" runat="server" onserverclick="btnSave_ServerClick">
```

Page attributes

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="ViewWarrantyContract.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" EnableEventValidation = "false"  Inherits="FANUC.CSMS.CustomerSupport.Web.ViewWarrantyContract" enableViewState="True" %>
```

Onserverclick function

```
rowFilter["WRNT_Warranty_No"] = Request.QueryString["WRNT_Warranty_No"];
```

Page Load function

```
        protected void Page_Load( object sender, System.EventArgs e )   {

        try {

            if ( Request.QueryString[ "MESSAGE" ] != null && Request.QueryString[ "MESSAGE" ] != "" )   objErrorDisplay.MessageCode = Request.QueryString[ "MESSAGE" ];

            string  strWarrCommData = Request.QueryString[ Constants.QS_DATA_FLAG ];

            if ( strWarrCommData != null && strWarrCommData.Trim().Equals( Constants.QS_COMMISSION_DATA ) ) bWarrantyScreen = false;


            strScreenMode =  Request.QueryString[ Constants.SESSION_MODE ];

            if ( strScreenMode == null )    strScreenMode = Constants.SCREEN_MODE_MODIFY;
            if ( strScreenMode == "" )      strScreenMode = Constants.SCREEN_MODE_MODIFY;

            hdnScreenMode.Value = strScreenMode;

            ApplyPermissions();

            Localize();

            BindDropDowns();

            if ( !IsPostBack && strScreenMode != Constants.SCREEN_MODE_NEW )    this.GetWarrantyContractData();     //gets the data from the db if the page is loaded for the first time.       

            SetControlStyleByScreenMode(); //sets control styles depending on screen type based on query string. 

        }
        catch ( FANUCBaseException fbeEx )  {
            objErrorDisplay.ErrorToLog = fbeEx;
        }
    }
```

SetControlStyle method

```
        private void SetControlStyleByScreenMode()  {
        if ( strScreenMode == Constants.SCREEN_MODE_NEW )   this.txtSeibanNoValue.ReadOnly  = false;
        else                                                this.txtSeibanNoValue.ReadOnly  = true;
    }
```

Update:
Apparently the querystring comes empty on the page load function as well. Weird thing is it happens only on post back. On the first load, querystring object is not null.

Function that loads the page for the first time:

```
        protected void btnModify_ServerClick( object sender, System.EventArgs e )   {

        try {

            this.StoreValuesInSession();

            string  strMode = Constants.SCREEN_MODE_MODIFY;

            string  strURL  = "../CustomerSupport/ViewWarrantyContract.aspx?" + Constants.QS_DATA_FLAG + "=";

            if ( bWarrantyScreen )  strURL  += Constants.QS_WARRANTY_DATA;
            else                    strURL  += Constants.QS_COMMISSION_DATA;

            Row[]   objCustSelected = oWC.GetRowsObject( new string[]{ "WRNT_Warranty_No" }, true );
            string  strWarrantyNo   = Convert.ToString( objCustSelected[ 0 ][ "WRNT_Warranty_No" ] );

            strURL  +=  "&" + Constants.SESSION_MODE + "=" + strMode + "&" + "WRNT_Warranty_No" + "=" + strWarrantyNo;

            Response.Redirect( strURL );
        }
        catch ( FANUCBaseException fbeEx )  {
            objErrorDisplay.ErrorToLog              = fbeEx;
            this.oWC.DisplayGridWithExistingState   = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using asynchronous postbacks (e.g. UpdatePanels)?

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: I am unsure what code I need to post here. :/

@FrédéricHamidi No. It is simple `onserverclick` function call doing a regular postback.

Comment: Posting the server-side code that attempts to read the query string would be a good start I think.

Comment: Done. Let me know, if I should post the full function.

Comment: Okay, we still need more information about your strategy. You say *My server receives the default url, even though browser display querystring in the address bar.* How exactly are you modifying the query string on the client-side?

Comment: Added the code that redirects to this page and create the querystring.

Comment: In the onserverclick, all I do is use the querystring function to read the data, and update the database.